# IIS 8 And redirect for a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, iis

Is there a way in IIS 8.0 to redirect a request for a specific file to another file?  For example, if I have this relative path in a static html page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="../res/topframe.js"></script>
```

The topframe.js file is broken- and I need to have every request for 'topframe.js' instead serve up the javascript found in the corrected file 'topframefixed.js', which may have a url like:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://mywebserver/scripts/topframefixed.js"></script>
```

I have full control of the IIS server, but I cannot edit those static html pages (there are 1000's of them).  And I think it complicates things that the path to the broken js file is relative- the absolute url is different for every one of those static pages.  So I would really have to redirect the call to a specific file name, not the whole url.

Is this possible?  Or maybe another way to accomplish this outside of IIS?  I have looked at the HTTP Redirect funcion in IIS manager, I don't see that it would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out.  It might be possible to do this through IIS manager, but I wasn't able to find a way... but I was able to do this using wildcard redirects.  I edited my IIS server web.config to look like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
        <add wildcard="*topframe.js" destination="http://mywebserver/scripts/topframefixed.js" />
    </httpRedirect>
</system.webServer>
```

And it worked.